# BIGQUERY moving average with missing values

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, moving-average

I have the following data

```
with dummy_data as 
(
SELECT '2017-01-01' as ref_month, 18 as value, 1 as id
UNION ALL SELECT '2017-02-01' as ref_month, 20 as value, 1 as id
UNION ALL SELECT '2017-03-01' as ref_month, 22 as value, 1 as id
-- UNION ALL SELECT '2017-04-01' as ref_month, 28 as value, 1 as id
UNION ALL SELECT '2017-05-01' as ref_month, 30 as value, 1 as id
UNION ALL SELECT '2017-06-01' as ref_month, 37 as value, 1 as id
UNION ALL SELECT '2017-07-01' as ref_month, 42 as value, 1 as id
-- UNION ALL SELECT '2017-08-01' as ref_month, 55 as value, 1 as id
-- UNION ALL SELECT '2017-09-01' as ref_month, 49 as value, 1 as id
UNION ALL SELECT '2017-10-01' as ref_month, 51 as value, 1 as id
UNION ALL SELECT '2017-11-01' as ref_month, 57 as value, 1 as id
UNION ALL SELECT '2017-12-01' as ref_month, 56 as value, 1 as id
UNION ALL SELECT '2017-01-01' as ref_month, 18 as value, 2 as id
UNION ALL SELECT '2017-02-01' as ref_month, 20 as value, 2 as id
UNION ALL SELECT '2017-03-01' as ref_month, 22 as value, 2 as id
UNION ALL SELECT '2017-04-01' as ref_month, 28 as value, 2 as id
-- UNION ALL SELECT '2017-05-01' as ref_month, 30 as value, 2 as id
-- UNION ALL SELECT '2017-06-01' as ref_month, 37 as value, 2 as id
UNION ALL SELECT '2017-07-01' as ref_month, 42 as value, 2 as id
UNION ALL SELECT '2017-08-01' as ref_month, 55 as value, 2 as id
UNION ALL SELECT '2017-09-01' as ref_month, 49 as value, 2 as id
-- UNION ALL SELECT '2017-10-01' as ref_month, 51 as value, 2 as id
UNION ALL SELECT '2017-11-01' as ref_month, 57 as value, 2 as id
UNION ALL SELECT '2017-12-01' as ref_month, 56 as value, 2 as id
)
```

And i want to calculate the moving average for each id. I know you can do something like the following

```
select 
    id
  , ref_month
  , avg(value) over (partition by id order by ref_month ROWS BETWEEN 5 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) as moving_avg
from 
    dummy_data
```

but as you can see from my dummy data, there are some missing values.
 Any ideas on how to calculate the moving average easily when there are some missing values? 
I was thinking to calculate first a full date range

```
date_range AS
(
  SELECT reference_month
  FROM UNNEST(
      GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d', (SELECT MIN(ref_month) FROM dummy_data)), PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d', (SELECT MAX(ref_month) FROM dummy_data)), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
  ) AS reference_month
)
```

and then do a cartesian products with the ids and then join back with my dummy data, but this seems an anti pattern. Any idea on how to do this optimally?
Thanks

EDIT:

expected result:
For id 1:

```
2017-01-01  18
2017-02-01  19
2017-03-01  20
2017-05-01  18
2017-06-01  21.8
2017-07-01  26.2
2017-10-01  26
2017-11-01  30
2017-12-01  32.8
```

For id 2:

```
2017-01-01  18
2017-02-01  19
2017-03-01  20
2017-04-01  22
2017-07-01  18.4
2017-08-01  25
2017-09-01  29.2
2017-11-01  40.6
2017-12-01  43.4
```

Comment: how you want to treat missing values as 0? as NULL? or somehow differently? btw, the way you have now is as if you treat missing as NULL - right?

Comment: I'd like 0, because the correct way to compute the moving average would be to have 0 when the data is missing right? I am trying to calculate this in the most efficient way, without a cartesian product that would make my data explode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and actually works! :o)
It assumes that your ref_month is of `DATE` data type (if in your case you have it as `STRING` - still Okay - see note at the very bottom of my answer)

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  id, 
  ref_month,
  ROUND(SUM(value) OVER (rolling_six_days) / 
    (LAST_VALUE(month_pos) OVER (rolling_six_days) 
      - FIRST_VALUE(month_pos) OVER (rolling_six_days)
      + 1)
  ) AS correct_moving_avg
FROM (
  SELECT id, ref_month, value,
    DATE_DIFF(ref_month, '2016-01-01', MONTH) month_pos
  FROM dummy_data
)
WINDOW rolling_six_days AS 
  (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY month_pos RANGE BETWEEN 5 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW )
```

You can test / play with it using your example data as below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH dummy_data AS (
  SELECT DATE '2017-01-01' AS ref_month, 18 AS value, 1 AS id
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-02-01' AS ref_month, 20 AS value, 1 AS id
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-03-01' AS ref_month, 22 AS value, 1 AS id
  -- UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-04-01' as ref_month, 28 as value, 1 as id
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-05-01' AS ref_month, 30 AS value, 1 AS id
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-06-01' AS ref_month, 37 AS value, 1 AS id
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-07-01' AS ref_month, 42 AS value, 1 AS id
  -- UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-08-01' as ref_month, 55 as value, 1 as id
  -- UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-09-01' as ref_month, 49 as value, 1 as id
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-10-01' AS ref_month, 51 AS value, 1 AS id
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-11-01' AS ref_month, 57 AS value, 1 AS id
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-12-01' AS ref_month, 56 AS value, 1 AS id
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-01-01' AS ref_month, 18 AS value, 2 AS id
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-02-01' AS ref_month, 20 AS value, 2 AS id
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-03-01' AS ref_month, 22 AS value, 2 AS id
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-04-01' AS ref_month, 28 AS value, 2 AS id
  -- UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-05-01' as ref_month, 30 as value, 2 as id
  -- UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-06-01' as ref_month, 37 as value, 2 as id
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-07-01' AS ref_month, 42 AS value, 2 AS id
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-08-01' AS ref_month, 55 AS value, 2 AS id
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-09-01' AS ref_month, 49 AS value, 2 AS id
  -- UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-10-01' as ref_month, 51 as value, 2 as id
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-11-01' AS ref_month, 57 AS value, 2 AS id
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-12-01' AS ref_month, 56 AS value, 2 AS id
)
SELECT 
  id, 
  ref_month,
  ROUND(SUM(value) OVER (rolling_six_days) / 
    (LAST_VALUE(month_pos) OVER (rolling_six_days) 
      - FIRST_VALUE(month_pos) OVER (rolling_six_days)
      + 1)
  ) AS correct_moving_avg
FROM (
  SELECT id, ref_month, value,
    DATE_DIFF(ref_month, '2016-01-01', MONTH) month_pos
  FROM dummy_data
)
WINDOW rolling_six_days AS (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY month_pos RANGE BETWEEN 5 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW )
ORDER BY 1,2
```

To help you in exploring logic  - see below "expanded" version of above query - it has all even intermediate values propagated up to very outside select so you can see everything ...

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH dummy_data AS 
(
  SELECT DATE '2017-01-01' AS ref_month, 18 AS value, 1 AS id
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-02-01' AS ref_month, 20 AS value, 1 AS id
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-03-01' AS ref_month, 22 AS value, 1 AS id
  -- UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-04-01' as ref_month, 28 as value, 1 as id
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-05-01' AS ref_month, 30 AS value, 1 AS id
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-06-01' AS ref_month, 37 AS value, 1 AS id
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-07-01' AS ref_month, 42 AS value, 1 AS id
  -- UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-08-01' as ref_month, 55 as value, 1 as id
  -- UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-09-01' as ref_month, 49 as value, 1 as id
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-10-01' AS ref_month, 51 AS value, 1 AS id
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-11-01' AS ref_month, 57 AS value, 1 AS id
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-12-01' AS ref_month, 56 AS value, 1 AS id
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-01-01' AS ref_month, 18 AS value, 2 AS id
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-02-01' AS ref_month, 20 AS value, 2 AS id
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-03-01' AS ref_month, 22 AS value, 2 AS id
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-04-01' AS ref_month, 28 AS value, 2 AS id
  -- UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-05-01' as ref_month, 30 as value, 2 as id
  -- UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-06-01' as ref_month, 37 as value, 2 as id
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-07-01' AS ref_month, 42 AS value, 2 AS id
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-08-01' AS ref_month, 55 AS value, 2 AS id
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-09-01' AS ref_month, 49 AS value, 2 AS id
  -- UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-10-01' as ref_month, 51 as value, 2 as id
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-11-01' AS ref_month, 57 AS value, 2 AS id
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-12-01' AS ref_month, 56 AS value, 2 AS id
)
SELECT 
  id,
  ref_month,
  value,
  moving_sum,
  first_month,
  last_month,
  ROUND(moving_sum / (last_month - first_month + 1)) AS correct_moving_avg,
  moving_avg
FROM (
  SELECT
    id,
    ref_month,
    value,
    SUM(value) OVER (rolling_six_days) AS moving_sum,
    FIRST_VALUE(month_pos) OVER (rolling_six_days) AS first_month,
    LAST_VALUE(month_pos) OVER (rolling_six_days) AS last_month,
    AVG(value) OVER (rolling_six_days) AS moving_avg
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      id, ref_month, value,
      DATE_DIFF(ref_month, '2016-01-01', MONTH) month_pos
    FROM dummy_data
  )
  WINDOW rolling_six_days AS 
    (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY month_pos RANGE BETWEEN 5 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW )
)
ORDER BY 1,2
```

with result as

```sql
id  ref_month   value moving_sum    first_month last_month  correct_moving_avg  moving_avg   
1    2017-01-01 18    18            12          12          18.0                  18.0   
1    2017-02-01 20    38            12          13          19.0                  19.0   
1    2017-03-01 22    60            12          14          20.0                  20.0   
1    2017-05-01 30    90            12          16          18.0                  22.5   
1    2017-06-01 37    127           12          17          21.0                  25.4   
1    2017-07-01 42    151           13          18          25.0                  30.2   
1    2017-10-01 51    160           16          21          27.0                  40.0   
1    2017-11-01 57    187           17          22          31.0                  46.75  
1    2017-12-01 56    206           18          23          34.0                  51.5   
2    2017-01-01 18    18            12          12          18.0                  18.0   
2    2017-02-01 20    38            12          13          19.0                  19.0   
2    2017-03-01 22    60            12          14          20.0                  20.0   
2    2017-04-01 28    88            12          15          22.0                  22.0   
2    2017-07-01 42    112           13          18          19.0                  28.0   
2    2017-08-01 55    147           14          19          25.0                  36.75  
2    2017-09-01 49    174           15          20          29.0                  43.5   
2    2017-11-01 57    203           18          22          41.0                  50.75  
2    2017-12-01 56    259           18          23          43.0                  51.8
```

hope this shows/explains you the approach

Note: if your `ref_month` field is of STRING` data tyoe you should slightly adjust line with DATE_DIFF - it should be as

```sql
DATE_DIFF(cast(ref_month as DATE), '2016-01-01', MONTH) month_pos
```

Note 2: I picked '2016-01-01' as a starting point for counting months - but you can pick any to make sure that it is less than your minimum date - for example '2000-01-01' will perfectly work too

Comment: OK this is the one working! it is a bit off due to the rounding, plus you are actually calculating a 6 days rolling window, but I figure out how to adapt it thanks to the expanded version. Great! thank you!

Comment: six days came from your original query that I have not changed  - to have it for 5 days change 5 to 4 in `RANGE BETWEEN 5 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
with dummy_data as 
(
SELECT '2017-01-01' as ref_month, 18 as value, 1 as id
UNION ALL SELECT '2017-02-01' as ref_month, 20 as value, 1 as id
UNION ALL SELECT '2017-03-01' as ref_month, 22 as value, 1 as id
-- UNION ALL SELECT '2017-04-01' as ref_month, 28 as value, 1 as id
UNION ALL SELECT '2017-05-01' as ref_month, 30 as value, 1 as id
UNION ALL SELECT '2017-06-01' as ref_month, 37 as value, 1 as id
UNION ALL SELECT '2017-07-01' as ref_month, 42 as value, 1 as id
-- UNION ALL SELECT '2017-08-01' as ref_month, 55 as value, 1 as id
-- UNION ALL SELECT '2017-09-01' as ref_month, 49 as value, 1 as id
UNION ALL SELECT '2017-10-01' as ref_month, 51 as value, 1 as id
UNION ALL SELECT '2017-11-01' as ref_month, 57 as value, 1 as id
UNION ALL SELECT '2017-12-01' as ref_month, 56 as value, 1 as id
UNION ALL SELECT '2017-01-01' as ref_month, 18 as value, 2 as id
UNION ALL SELECT '2017-02-01' as ref_month, 20 as value, 2 as id
UNION ALL SELECT '2017-03-01' as ref_month, 22 as value, 2 as id
UNION ALL SELECT '2017-04-01' as ref_month, 28 as value, 2 as id
-- UNION ALL SELECT '2017-05-01' as ref_month, 30 as value, 2 as id
-- UNION ALL SELECT '2017-06-01' as ref_month, 37 as value, 2 as id
UNION ALL SELECT '2017-07-01' as ref_month, 42 as value, 2 as id
UNION ALL SELECT '2017-08-01' as ref_month, 55 as value, 2 as id
UNION ALL SELECT '2017-09-01' as ref_month, 49 as value, 2 as id
-- UNION ALL SELECT '2017-10-01' as ref_month, 51 as value, 2 as id
UNION ALL SELECT '2017-11-01' as ref_month, 57 as value, 2 as id
UNION ALL SELECT '2017-12-01' as ref_month, 56 as value, 2 as id
)


select 
    id
  , ref_month
  , avg(avg(value)) over (partition by id order by ref_month) as moving_avg
from 
    dummy_data
    group by id
  , ref_month
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to treat the values as 0 and you want "5", then a series of `lag()` might be the simplest approach:

```
select id, ref_month,
       (value +
        (case when lag(ref_month) over (partition by id order by ref_month) > date_add(ref_month, interval -4 month)
              then lag(value, 1) over (partition by id order by ref_month)
              else 0
         end) +
        (case when lag(ref_month, 2) over (partition by id order by ref_month) > date_add(ref_month, interval -4 month)
              then lag(value, 2) over (partition by id order by ref_month)
              else 0
         end) +
        (case when lag(ref_month, 3) over (partition by id order by ref_month) > date_add(ref_month, interval -4 month)
              then lag(value, 3) over (partition by id order by ref_month)
              else 0
         end) +
        (case when lag(ref_month, 4) over (partition by id order by ref_month) > date_add(ref_month, interval -4 month)
              then lag(value, 4) over (partition by id order by ref_month)
              else 0
         end)
       ) / 
       least(5, date_diff(min(ref_month) over (partition by id), ref_month))
from dummy_data;
```

The query is more complicated than the logic.  It basically adds up the five most recent values dividing by 5.  But it takes boundary conditions into affect (along with missing values).