# bigquery order by date in analytical function not working?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Here is the sample data

```
    WITH dummy_data AS (
  SELECT DATE '2017-01-01' AS ref_month, 18 AS value, 1 AS id
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-02-01' AS ref_month, 20 AS value, 1 AS id
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-03-01' AS ref_month, 22 AS value, 1 AS id
  -- UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-04-01' as ref_month, 28 as value, 1 as id
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-05-01' AS ref_month, 30 AS value, 1 AS id
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-06-01' AS ref_month, 37 AS value, 1 AS id
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-07-01' AS ref_month, 42 AS value, 1 AS id
  -- UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-08-01' as ref_month, 55 as value, 1 as id
  -- UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-09-01' as ref_month, 49 as value, 1 as id
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-10-01' AS ref_month, 51 AS value, 1 AS id
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-11-01' AS ref_month, 57 AS value, 1 AS id
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-12-01' AS ref_month, 56 AS value, 1 AS id
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-01-01' AS ref_month, 18 AS value, 2 AS id
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-02-01' AS ref_month, 20 AS value, 2 AS id
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-03-01' AS ref_month, 22 AS value, 2 AS id
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-04-01' AS ref_month, 28 AS value, 2 AS id
  -- UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-05-01' as ref_month, 30 as value, 2 as id
  -- UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-06-01' as ref_month, 37 as value, 2 as id
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-07-01' AS ref_month, 42 AS value, 2 AS id
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-08-01' AS ref_month, 55 AS value, 2 AS id
--   UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-09-01' AS ref_month, 49 AS value, 2 AS id
  -- UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-10-01' as ref_month, 51 as value, 2 as id
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-11-01' AS ref_month, 57 AS value, 2 AS id
  UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-12-01' AS ref_month, 56 AS value, 2 AS id
)
```

I am trying to run this simple query

```
select
id 
,value
, ref_month
, ARRAY_AGG(value) OVER w1 as agg_last_3_values
from dummy_data
window w1 as (partition by id order by ref_month RANGE BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
```

Why do I get the following error?

```
ORDER BY key must be numeric in a RANGE-based window with OFFSET PRECEDING or OFFSET FOLLOWING boundaries, but has type DATE
```

I don't see why it shouldn't be able to deal with dates.... any suggestions?

Comment: Not super familiar with bigquery, but in most SQL languages the window functions go with the select list, and not after from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use RANGE the key in ORDER BY must be numeric
Looks like you are trying to adopt query from [`BIGQUERY moving average with missing values`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49883311/bigquery-moving-average-with-missing-values) , but please take attention to `month_pos` calculated field used there

You can use something like below to address this:

```
DATE_DIFF(ref_month, '2016-01-01', MONTH) month_pos
```

Also, wanted to point - use of `RANGE` vs. `ROWS` here quite important because window function is applied on set of rows not based on the rows position but rather on the value of month

Comment: hey thanks, no I am using the same dummy data but trying to solve a different problem. My problem was I confused RANGE vs. ROWS

Comment: I do understand this. Still wanted in my answer to emphasize the difference between ROWS and RANGE. Question is not 100% clear to me  - but somehow I feel you need RANGE there  - not ROWS :o) So i would recommend to take another look and do extra testing to see if you really getting what is expected :o)

Comment: I see what you mean, i looked more into it and I understand better your point now. But I am not changing the  'BIGQUERY moving average with missing values'. I am actually doing something different now. Which has no missing values, and therefore should be fine.  But your point actually taught me a lot about the difference between the two. Thanks.

Comment: glad to hear this :o) of course if there is no missing values ROWS will work. your example in question has missing values and that is why I was "insisting" on you to double check :o)

Comment: you are very right, my example has missing values, and your suggestion was spot on. It was my mistake not having  good example, but I actually didn't grasp very well the difference RANGE vs. ROWS, which now I do.

Answer (score 4):

Use `rows` instead of `range`:

```
select id, value, ref_month, ARRAY_AGG(value) OVER w1 as agg_last_3_values
from dummy_data
window w1 as (partition by id order by ref_month ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
```

`range` is tricky, because it has to handle ties -- so rows with the same value of the sort key are included in the window.  This usually results in hard-to-debug errors, but it is occasionally useful.

I am not familiar with restrictions on the `order by` for `range` in other languages.  However, it would seem that BigQuery is assuming that the `order by` key is numeric.